# select event not fired on the same item

Tags: sapui5

I have a master-detail splitapp use for phone browser. Master page display the main list and when I click on an item, it will navigate to detail page.

The problem is, from detail page, I click on `BackArrow` to back to master page and tap again on the same item, `onSelect` event won't fire > no go anywhere. But if I tap on another item, it works.

In `manifest.json`, master viewlevel = 1 and detail viewlevel = 2.

Thanks

Below is the detail page navigation button

```
<Page
title="Title text"
showNavButton="true"
navButtonPress="onNavBack">
```

onNavBack function

```js
onNavBack: function (oEvent) {
  var oHistory = History.getInstance();
  var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();

  if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
      window.history.go(-1);
  } else {
  // no history handle
}}
```

onSelect to forward

```js
, onSelect : function(oEvent) {
    var oTransferData = this.createTransferData(oContext);
    this.transferData.setData(oTransferData);
...
this.getRouter().navTo(
    "detail", { ZITEM : oTransferData.ZITEM }
);
}
    
, createTransferData : function(oContext) {
    var oData = {};    
    oData.ZITEM = oContext.getProperty("ZITEM");
}
```

the list

```html
<List
    id="masterList"
    noDataText="no data"
    mode="SingleSelectMaster"
    selectionChange="onSelect"
    includeItemInSelection="true"
>
```

Comment: SplittApp floorpaln for master detail is outdated! The new floorplan for this scenario is the FlexibleColumnLayout, please consider using that before continueing: experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/flexible-column-layout

Comment: thanks, I do aware of it but I'm working on quite old libraries so can't help

Comment: unlucky, but its good to hear your up to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **itemPress** event instead of select (make sure item has "Active" in its **type** property). It fires whenever you click on item, and select only fires when the selection changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the list selection

**Code**

```
var oList = sap.ui.getCore().byId("masterList");
if(oList)
  oList .removeSelections(true);
```